# Removing an appended image from a jQuery Dialog Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've gone through the various solutions on StackOverflow, and I haven't had any success in making them work.  I can add an image easily to the dialog, but various attempts to remove it don't work so I wind up with multiple images.

Note that I don't want it to appear on ALL dialogs, just a series of welcome dialogs.  This is the code so far (for one of them):

```
 $("#welcomeScreen").dialog({
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            position: "center",
            dialogClass: 'help-dialog',
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 200,
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("#myNewImage").remove();
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<img src='Images/question.png' id='myNewImage' />");
            }
        }).parents(".ui-dialog").css("opacity", "0.9");
```

The dialogClass changes the background colour for these dialogs.

I have also tried:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove('#myNewImage');
```

which doesn't work, and subsequent openings appends another icon on the title bar.  I also tried

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
```

which removed the entire title bar (which I kind of expected).

So really, I just want this icon to appear in the title bar for a couple of dialogs, and not on any of the others.  What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Someone kindly answered the question which I was about to accept as it resolved this issue, but they deleted their response.  I'll post their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion Your code does works :)

Check my jsfiddle of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FYhNw/1/

Button ADD add's IMG - REMOVE removes it!

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<img src='Images/question.png' id='myNewImage' />");   

$("#myNewImage").remove();
```

And thats Your code :) - so remove does what it's suppose to do! :)

If you wish for this img to show only in few dialogs do an IF statement.

Comment: Trust me, it really doesn't work in my app. :)   But `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").find('#myNewImage').remove();` does :)  I have an additional issue now with timings between closing this dialog and opening the next removing it in the `close:` event, but I'll deal with that separately.

Comment: Ok :) Good luck! Hope I would be able to use the functionality You are building currently someday! :)